# How to link a binary with the library with the version name

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, shared-libraries

Let I've compiler a `so` shared library with g++ as the following

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.1.0 -o libtest.1.0.1 test.o
```

But when I'm trying to link a binary with this lib a write the following:

```
g++ -o bin -L. -ltest -Wl,-rpath.
```

linker trying to search `libtest.so` without any version number.

How can I pass to the `-l` linker option the lib name with the version number?

Comment: You should name your library file properly.

Comment: @LeeDuhem Thanks for your comment! Did you mean that I must to create a libtest.so besides the libtest.so.1.0.1?

Comment: No, it is recommended, not something you have to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
g++ -o bin -L. -Wl,-rpath=. -l:libtest.1.0.1
```

Normally, on Linux at least, with `-lnamespace`, `ld` will try to find a file named `libnamespace.so` or `libnamespace.a` to link in its library search path list, but with `-l:namespace`, `ld` will search for a file named `namespace` in its library search path list.

Comment: AWESOME!!! You are wizard! Many thanks, it works for me. I tried to fix this problem a few days...

Comment: @St.Antario It comes from the explanation of `-l` option of `ld`. Next time you will know where to find out the answer by yourself :-)